# Simulating a hard-link to a directory

Tags: directory, hard-link

I have a kind of problem. I am trying to hard-link all my dotfiles [files that customize certain apps] in one folder for ease of use, called ~/dotfiles/ , but multiple programs that I have, have entire directories for that. Some are in .config, some just have a directory at the home folder, so I tried to check whether I could hard-link a directory.

After looking into it, I saw all the problems, warning, etc. about hard-linking directories, and why it's a giant nono. So I'm fully discouraged from hard-linking directories, however, I still need to do it somehow.

I found a way around this, which is by creating directories within ~/dotfiles/ and hardlinking the contents of the directories INTO those created ones, but that immediately hit a brick wall called **boredom and repetition**. A bunch of programs had multiple dirs, some with nested directories, and I didn't feel like spending a lot of time creating directories just so that I'm able to hard-link config files.

All I'm wondering is this. **Is there a way to simulate a hard-link?**

For example, I have a directory called ~/Testconfig/, and I want to hard-link it into ~/dotfiles/. *Theoretically,* a hardlink would place a directory in ~/dotfiles/ with all of it's contents, including its files and its nested directories.

Is there a way to achieve that without actually creating a hardlink?

My idea is that a bash script could be made that automates all of this, but I know next to nothing about bash, so that would be difficult.

Comment: What is your goal? Maybe there's a better way to reach the goal than what you're trying to do...

Comment: My goal is to put all dotfiles into a single directory. I'm looking into alternatives, like YADM and GNU Stow, but since they seem more complicated/specialised than I'm ready to deal with [for now], I'm trying to achieve this with hard-links.

Comment: In this scenario I imagine it's for easier overview and access? If so, symlinks should work Just Fine?

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot. I also want to have a github repository for all my dotfiles. I tried symlinks, but that ended up with a repo full of symlinks and not much content.

Comment: That makes sense :)

Comment: It makes sense to have a git repository of all your dotfiles. But why would they all need to be in the same folder?

Comment: First of all, it's not a duplicate of that question. Nowhere near. Secondly, it's easier to just have one folder for one repo, so that when I update multiple files I can just go in ~/dotfiles rather than multiple folders.

Comment: I beg to disagree. Why would you want to update several files at once? Why would that be more difficult when you don't have them in one directory? These are unrelated dotfiles, they have their location in the file system and that's where you should edit them. I don't see any benefit in having all of these files in one directory. Googling for "github dotfiles" relieves hundreds of user that do it exactly this way (not that this necessarily is a good argument, but still...).

Comment: They're all in their own places seperately, but what I meant was that I wanted all of them hardlinked to a single directory. So that when I wanted to commit those changes, I could just go to ~/dotfiles and run the commands once. If I committed after every single modification I made it'd take an hour, I sometimes forget to commit.

Comment: I understand that, but I still don't see why you need to have all dotfiles in one directory. If you want to commit all changes, you do `git commit -a`. It won't matter for `git` where those files are stored on your disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `cp -al .??* ~/dotfiles/` and let it worry about all the complexity. Directories are created and files are linked

Comment: Seems to work perfectly so far! Although I don't want to save EVERY dotfile that exists, so I changed the .??* part.